# Sql Query in multiple column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called attorney with the following columns:

```
ID  |   Practice Area  |   City  |   State
```

Now if a user wants to search like this *personal injury new jercy alabama*:

```
ID   |   Practice Area   |   City       |   State
Id   |   personal injury |   new jercy  |   alabama
```

How can we write a SQL query which returns this result set?

Regards

Comment: All the A,B,C will in practice area column ?? post the correct input and output what you want

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Lets say if we type Personal injury, Daphne, AL then it should feth all the record whose Practice area = personal injury, whose state is daphne and whose state is AL. moreover there will be raw string which should be searched in practice area, city and state column.

Comment: When you say raw string do you mean that it should work also with things like "alabama injury" or "personal injury los angeles" or whatever which isn't in the same exact format?

Comment: `Contains` may help you -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: James yes it could be only alabma injury or personal injury lost angeles

Comment: @ImranAhmadMughal, Why not separate each parameters, rather than one string with undefined pattern?

Comment: lets say we spearate each of them with comma then what about the ordering @wewesthemenace

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Instead of using 1 parameter (comma-delimited or not), why not pass 3 parameters? 1 for practice area, city, and state.

Comment: @wewesthemenace, we have only one textbox UI so that is not  possible.

Comment: Then, you may want to redesign your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT ID, [Practice Area], City, State FROM Attorney
WHERE @Parameter Like '%' + [Practice Area] + '%' OR 
@Parameter Like '%' + City + '%' OR @Parameter Like '%' + State + '%'
```

`@Parameter` will be your text i.e. 'personal injury new jersey alabama' in your case

Comment: city can come first, then practice area and the state. So order of these column in search can very.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search exactly what user input, we can do this by this code:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [PracticeArea]+ ' ' + [City] + ' ' + [State] = @Parameter
```

In order is search by '%'

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [PracticeArea]+ ' ' + [City] + ' ' + [State] LIKE '%'+@Parameter+'%'
```

Comment: city can come first, then practice area and the state. So order of these column in search can very.