# Raw string to search in multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Profile with the following columns

```
1) ID
2) Name
3) Course
4) Address
```

I want to search "John Math Dubai" Here John is Name, Math is Course & Dubai is Address. Moreover the order can be random in search string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Query in multiple column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422414/sql-query-in-multiple-column)

Comment: you have tried anything till now

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question multiple times

Comment: Also, since your question 12 hours ago was about SQL Server, I'll assume this one is too. Please don't add tags that are not related to your problem

Answer (score 0):

as per my assumption you are looking for this one

```
declare @t table (
Id varchar(10),
Name varchar(10),
course varchar(10),
Address varchar(10))
insert into @t (Id,Name,course,Address)values (1,'john','math','dubai')
```

**using PATINDEX and COALESCE**

```
select * from @t
WHERE PATINDEX('%john math dubai%',COALESCE(Name,' ') +' ' + COALESCE(course,' ') + ' ' +COALESCE(Address,' '))>0
```